# How to use Log4J2 composite configuration with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1 starter with log4j2 using following POM. WAR file is hosted in Tomcat 8 (instead of using embedded tomcat). Application logs are written to console instead of writing to log file. Apparently Spring Boot's XML configuration is overwrites the one configured in application.

POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Log4j2 uses composite configuration where configuration is split in 2 xml files: `log4j2-base.xml` and `log4j2-env.xml`

Resources directory contains `log4j2.component.properties` with following content:

```
log4j.configurationFile=log4j2-base.xml,log4j2-env.xml
```

Resources directory also contains `log4j2-base.xml`. File `log4j2-env.xml` is part of environment specific JAR file that is already placed into class path.

Log:

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml] initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@40575bb9 [configurations=[XmlConfiguration[location=/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2-base.xml], XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/lib/myProject.jar!/log4j2-env.xml]], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@583fc0cb, rootNode=null, listeners=[], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@278307b, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@185463aa]...
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration notified 8 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration stopping 7 LoggerConfigs.
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager {}null
DEBUG StatusLogger All asynchronous threads have terminated
DEBUG StatusLogger RollingFileManager shutdown completed with status true
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down RollingFileManager null, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender RollingFile stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger CompositeConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 8 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@40575bb9 [configurations=[XmlConfiguration[location=/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2-base.xml], XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/usr/mware/jwsAppDetails/app1/lib/myProject.jar!/log4j2-env.xml]], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@583fc0cb, rootNode=null, listeners=[], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@278307b, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@185463aa] OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@77aa3299
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '2190fd23' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@64150381
```

Comment: Hi @zendu, were you able to make it work? I'm facing the same situation.

Comment: Hi @JPS, I indeed fixed this few days after posting this question. I have left the project since then and don't remember exact fix. I have asked team that still works on the project to post an answer here.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! I look forward to it.

Comment: Spring 2.6 has support for Log4j2’s Composite Configuration. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#new-and-noteworthy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We tried the following and it worked:

1. Rename the file log4j-base.xml to log4j2.xml
2. In log4j2.component.properties, rename log4j-base.xml to log4j2.xml
   like below:

   log4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml,log4j2-env.xml

Comment: Thanks @SukanyaPai, it worked for me. Is there any link to documentation (it would be nice to understand why `log4j2-something.xml` is not picked up)?

Comment: @skryvets To be honest, we did trial and error to fix it and luckily that got fixed. It would be great if anyone uploads a link to documentation if they find it.